# Determine $3:1$ coverings of $S^1 \times S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I have the following questions:

> Determine the number of (not necessarily connected) $3:1$ coverings of the torus.

I assume it is up to equivalence. I am not really sure what theorems I am suppose to use to approach this problem. I know there are theorems relating covering spaces and their induced subgroups, but I am not sure if this applies.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be unsure yourself what the problem is about, and unfortunately Readers will not have access to any surrounding context that clarifies the Question  (except as you can share that).  E.g. what sort of thing is meant here by "covering"?

Comment: Any covering of a path connected space has the property that the restriction to each path component is a covering map. Then the index of the entire covering is the sum of the index of each of the restrictions to a path component. So you should classify 1,2, and 3 sheeted connected coverings of $S^1 \times S^1 $ and partitions of the number 3.

Comment: I mean a Covering map

Comment: @ConnorMalin Okay, but how do you begin to find 1,2 and 3 sheeted coverings of $S^1 \times S^1$?

Comment: You should use those theorems you mentioned.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Since the number $n$-sheeted coverings correspond to index $n$ subgroups of $\pi_1(S^1 \times S^1) = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ we must find the number of index 1,2,3 subgroups of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. There is a single subgroup of index 1 and 3 subgroups of index 2. Thus, there are 3 such coverings with two path components. For 3 sheeted covers, there are 4 subgroups of index 3 and so there are 4 3-sheeted coverings. All together, there are 7.